# all possible ways to split a string based on a list of substrings

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list of substrings.

```
substrings = [A, B, C, D, AB, ABC, CD, DC]
```

I want to get all possible ways of splitting a string base on the above list. For example the output I need for `ABCDCA` is:

```
A, B, D, D, C, A
ABC, D, C, A
ABC, DC, A
AB, C, D, C, A
AB, CD, C, A
AB, C, DC, A
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a function with a for loop and yield the combinations.

After that try a list comprehension to filter out the ones that are in the `substrings` list, like this:

```
substrings = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB', 'ABC', 'CD', 'DC']
s = 'ABCDCA'
def splitter(s):
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        start = s[:i]
        end = s[i:]
        yield start, end
        for part in splitter(end):
            result = [start]
            result.extend(part)
            yield result

combinations = list(splitter(s))
print([i for i in combinations if (len(i) >= 3) and all(x in substrings for x in i)])
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'DC', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'CD', 'C', 'A'], ['AB', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'A'], ['AB', 'C', 'DC', 'A'], ['AB', 'CD', 'C', 'A'], ['ABC', 'D', 'C', 'A'], ['ABC', 'DC', 'A']]
```